# dapr | failed getting app id either from the URL path or the header dapr-app-id

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes-secrets, dapr, dapr-sidekick

I want to use a Java client to retrieve the dapr secrets. but I am getting exceptions while invoking. not sure where to set the `dapr-app-id` to resolve the issue. Help would be appriticated.

below is the java code I am using.

```
    String storeName = "local-secret-store";
    String secretName = "DB_MONGO_URI";
    DaprClient client = (new DaprClientBuilder()).build();
    Map<String, String> secret = client.getSecret(storeName, secretName).block();
```

Exception:

> io.dapr.exceptions.DaprException: UNIMPLEMENTED: HTTP status code 404
> invalid content-type: application/json headers:
> Metadata(:status=404,content-type=application/json,traceparent=00-b05653dd8bdddc976913e70bad7a7a85-3084603c8b1e7803-01,date=Thu,
> 30 Nov 2023 23:19:39 GMT,content-length=118)
> DATA-----------------------------
> {"errorCode":"ERR_DIRECT_INVOKE","message":"failed getting app id
> either from the URL path or the header dapr-app-id"}

Comment: I had a similar error, but in my case I had Traefik strip-prefix Middleware not correctly configured and hence ended up with a path like .../-dapr/v1.0/... instead of .../v1.0/...